# Wordpress: Consistent URLs and breadcrumb on post page

Tags: wordpress, url, permalinks, breadcrumbs, yoast

I'm working on a magzine page on a WordPress site. I want to get consitent URLs and breadcrumbs (Yoast) for SEO requirements.

I selected the magazin page, which I created under Pages, as the posts page in Settings -> Reading and now got the following URL for the magazine:

`www.example.com/magazine/`

In Settings -> Permalinks I got the following settings:

Individual structure: `/magazine/%category%/%postname%/`

**and**

for Category-Basis I put in `magazine`

In Yoast I selected to keep the category base.

Now I got the correct post URLs like I wanted:

`http://example/magazine/category/this-is-my-post-slug/`

But now there is the problem, that all posts are returning a 404 error. Another problem is, that the Yoast breadcrumb is not including the post page. So when I'm on a category it's in my example only `Start | Category` but should be `Start | Magazine | Category`

The other way around, when I remove `magazine` from the individual structure in permalinks, the posts dont have the right URL with `/magazine/` in it. Also the breadcrumb doesen't include the "Magazine" page.

I would appreceate any help and hints to fix the issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add `flush_rewrite_rules();` to your function.php

Comment: Hey @amarinediary, thanks but that doesen't do anything here.